# Will any graphics card work?

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I am looking into getting a cheap video card. I am currently looking at getting the  EVGA NVIDIA GeForce 210 PCI-E Graphics Card - 1 GB. Would this would with Ubuntu 12.10 and then later 13.04 and if so, how would I install the driver?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually check to see if the hardware is certified to work with Ubuntu before buying it: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/